# DB2 performance of coalesce and inner join

Tags: sql, db2

I have a pretty poorly performing query (which I inherited) and I'm not too sure how to optimize it... As far as I understand it's setting the value of a 2nd column as the value of the 1st column PLUS a value from another table, where a relationship is found.

```
update table1 set
col2 = col1 || coalesce (( 
    select table2.the_column_wanted from table2 where table2.fk = table1.pk and
    table2.flag = 'Y'))

where flag = 'Y' and pk in ( select distinct fk from table2 );
```

Comment: That `COALESCE()` is pointless, as if there's only 1 argument, it gets returned.  `COALESCE()` returns the first non-null argument it finds, or null if all arguments are null.

Answer (score 0):

The exact speed issue depends on the characteristics of your table, but in general I would look into `MERGE` for this sort of problem. Something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 USING table2
   ON table1.pk = table2.fk and 
      table1.flag = 'Y' and
      table2.flag = 'Y'
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
      table1.col2 = table1.col1 || table2.the_column_wanted;
```

The query as written is very questionable.  You should probably take a good look at all of the code you have "inherited."